# Poor wireless performance with RealTek RTL8723BE

Tags: wireless, networking, realtek

I have a laptop with the RealTek RTL8723BE. Performance is poor with long ping times, dropped packets and often on wake the network manager will report 'connected' but nothing with get through, pinging the router will get nothing. Other devices on the network have no problems, Windows running on same system has no problems.

Here is output of various possibly useful things:

```
$ sudo lshw -C network                                                 
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 28:e3:47:7d:f2:e9
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=3.13.0-32-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.69.101 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:18 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7d00000-f7d03fff

$ iwconfig
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"thebarn"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 00:23:69:8B:68:D6   
          Bit Rate=65 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=50/70  Signal level=-60 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:26   Missed beacon:0

$ ifconfig wlan0                                                            
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 28:e3:47:7d:f2:e9  
          inet addr:192.168.69.101  Bcast:192.168.69.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2ae3:47ff:fe7d:f2e9/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:30626 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:21527 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:35399437 (35.3 MB)  TX bytes:3244668 (3.2MB)
```

When adaptor is saying 'connected' and nothing is going through I try turning adaptor off and back on, then try rebooting with varying success.

So, my question: how do I get this adaptor working reliably like it does under Windows?

Answer (score 1):

This solution helped me - at least to not to drop the WiFi connection.

> echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf

The full explanation you can find here [14.04LTS and RTL8723BE WiFi drops - only reboot fixes](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2220933)

Comment: I've got `options rtl8723be fwlps=0 swlps=0` already in there. Found this through the forum thread https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new, worth a shot?

Answer (score 0):

Try to channel the wireless channel from 1 to 11 and check the performance

**Check the frequency and channel**

```
sudo nm-tool
```

**nm-tool** will list all of the visible wifi networks' frequencies.

```
sudo iwlist frequency
```

The command sudo **iwlist frequency** will give you a list of their corresponding wifi channel numbers.

Now change the channel to 11 with the following command

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 channel 11
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The channel is set in the router, not the wireless card.

Comment: Seems an odd solution, but gave it a go anyway. Got this for the last command `Error for wireless request "Set Frequency" (8B04) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Device or resource busy.` Would assume as it's connected to a channel that as mentioned above is set by the router.